# Blink led infinitely while the rest of the code is running in Matlab-Arduino

Tags: matlab, arduino

I am new to arduino and working on a college project about tic tac toe game. In there, main code must script on matlab using arduino. There are two players who can input and light up relevant leds.What I want is to blink the leds of player 2 until the game is finished. I cannot use while statement as it has to be run infinitely and hence the rest of the code unable to run. So what I can do to this problem? Is there any solutions available? 
Thank you.

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: Check [this link](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/286/how-can-i-create-multiple-running-threads) out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a timer interrupt to blink the LED without changing anything in your main loop.

Each time the timer 'fires' your interrupt handler is called, and in that handler you can turn the LED on and off.

[This](https://oscarliang.com/arduino-timer-and-interrupt-tutorial/) looks like a good tutorial on the subject.